# Weird errors when calling aiGetMaterialFloat (ASSIMP, C)

Tags: c, assimp

I am following [Assimp's documentation](http://www.assimp.org/lib_html/materials.html) to retrieve properties from a *struct aiMaterial* type. From their documentation, this is the usage of *aiGetMaterialString()*:

```
aiGetMaterialFloat(mat,<material-key>,<where-to-store>)
```

I was able to get the material name using *aiGetMaterialString()* and a propertie's color with *aiGetMaterialColor()*, for example, but adding this to my code:

```
float f = 1.0f;
aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, (float*)&f);
```

results in:

**`gcc src/*.c examples/game.c -o bin/game.o -lGL -lGLEW -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lassimp -lm`**

```
    In file included from /usr/include/assimp/scene.h:53:0,
                 from src/../include/mesh.h:13,
                 from src/mesh.c:1:
src/mesh.c: In function ‘mesh_setMaterialData’:
src/mesh.c:71:2: error: ‘pMat’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, (float*)&f);
  ^
src/mesh.c:71:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
src/mesh.c:71:2: error: ‘type’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, (float*)&f);
  ^
src/mesh.c:71:2: error: ‘pKey’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, (float*)&f);
  ^
src/mesh.c:71:2: error: ‘pOut’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, (float*)&f);
  ^
src/mesh.c:71:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘aiGetMaterialFloatArray’
  aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, (float*)&f);
  ^
make: *** [makefile:2: ALL] Error 1
```

(in my code, mat is of type struct aiMaterial*).

The code I am using is also basically the same thing that's described in assimp/material.h, line 1363:

> float specStrength = 1.f; // default value, remains unmodified if we fail.
>
> aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS_STRENGTH,
>      (float*)&specStrength);

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
This is the definition of *aiGetMaterialFloat*

```
#define aiGetMaterialFloat (pMat, type, index, pKey, pOut) \
    aiGetMaterialFloatArray(pMat, type, index, pKey, pOut, NULL)
```

and *aiGetMaterialFloatArray*

```
ASSIMP_API C_ENUM aiReturn aiGetMaterialFloatArray(const C_STRUCT aiMaterial* pMat, const char* pKey, unsigned int type, unsigned int index, float* pOut, unsigned int* pMax);
```

I replaced what I had earlier with:

```
aiGetMaterialFloatArray(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS, &f, NULL);
```

and it compiles... If I swap around the arguments on this function call I can get gcc  to tell me that the 4th argument I send is actually being perceived as the 6th for *aiGetMaterialFloatArray* (unsigned int* pMax). I really don't know enough about macros to understand what is going on.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the macro expansion. Check that you have the necessary includes (not sure if order matters). If that doesn't help, check the output from the preprocessor (compile mesh.c with `gcc -E`) and see what the line expands to.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I tried checking the output with -E but it's far too big, what should I look for?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck "grep aiGetMaterialFloat" doesn't even show any line containing aiGetMaterialFloat, only aiGetMaterialFloatArray

Comment: `aiGetMaterialFloat(mat, AI_MATKEY_SHININESS_STRENGTH, &f)` should be expanded to `aiGetMaterialFloatArray(mat, "$mat.shinpercent",0,0, &f, NULL)`. However, since the compiler complained about `pMat`, which is a parameter to the macro, I suspected that the expansion failed somehow. Your edit confirms my suspicion.